# Prevent term from asking me which shell to use

Tags: ansi-term, term

I want to use `/bin/bash` as default shell for `term` avoiding it to ask me every time.

Is this possible?

Comment: n.b. It needn't be a shell at all.  You can run anything in a terminal.  Your preferred shell is just provided as a convenient default, because *most* of the time people do want to run a shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to tell Emacs to use a default shell for `term`. However, when you call the `term` function from elisp code, you can specify the terminal program to use.

To use this, add the following to your configuration:

```lisp
(defun my-term ()
  (interactive)
  (term "/bin/bash"))
```

This defines a new command, which you can call as `M-x my-term`. You can change it to any name you like, as long as it doesn't conflict with an existing command name.

(You could also use [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) to change the way `M-x term` behaves, but that requires a bit more care to make sure you don't make problems for yourself)